# Adding random effects to glmer

Tags: r, lme4

I have a model with random effects (Customer IDs) that I calibrate using lme4's glmer function, giving me a model "M". I now want to update M by adding another batch of customer IDs along with corresponding data. How would I add this extra batch of customer IDs to calculate their random effects?

In other words, I don't want to update the calculated fixed effects of M. I just want to estimate the batch of random effects.

Comment: Do you want to keep the random-effects variances (and covariances) pinned at their estimated values as well, or do you want to update those on the basis of the new data?  (This question is not so easy to answer; there's a possibility that you will be better off figuring out how to do it by hand rather than through the package machinery ...)

Comment: @BenBolker: Ideally I'd like to keep the random effect variances pinned. I've crossposted this question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186322/glmer-sampling-random-effects

mainly because I'm not sure what the best approach is. My problem is that my dataset is huge so it's infeasible  to run my model on everything at once, which is why I'd like to somehow at least pin down the fixed effects and the random effect variance with a subset of data.